# Keyboard alignment issue with multiline text input

Tags: javascript, ios, typescript, react-native, react-native-textinput

I have also used KeyboardAvoidingView, this aligns the keyboard properly if its only single line but not with multiline.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position">
    <TextInput
     placeholder='input 1'
     placeholderTextColor='gray'
     multiline={true}
     onContentSizeChange={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.contentSize)}
     value='text 1'
    />
    <TextInput
     placeholder='input 2'
     placeholderTextColor='gray'
     multiline={true}
     onContentSizeChange={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.contentSize)}
     value='text 2'
    />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Is there any way to align the keyboard properly with multiline textInputs  in react native?

Answer (score 0):

It is working perfectly for me, may be it might be because of different versions, if that thing still doesn't work for you then you can use conditional alignment means as it is pressed the screen should scroll or you can use transform it with z-index